# Grant my code Event Log permissions

Tags: c#, event-log

Hi I am trying to grant my application full access to the event logs, so I have put this code in, and I am basicallyjust wondering if somebody who has used/seen this before can verify that what I have done is correct, or am I missing any steps?

```
        string thisMachineName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();

        EventLogPermission eventReaderPermission = new EventLogPermission(EventLogPermissionAccess.Administer, thisMachineName);
        eventReaderPermission.Demand();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Demand()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.codeaccesspermission.demand.aspx) method will throw a security exception at run time if your application does not already have Administer-level access to the event log. It will not grant permission.

Granting access is much more difficult than a single method call, I'm afraid. You should read-up on how to manage code access security.